# MySql Database - Optimizing the my.cnf file for dedicated server

Tags: mysql, database, configuration, my.cnf, dedicated

I have the following dedicated server configuration.

```
2 x Hexa-Core Xeon E5645 2.4GHz w/H (24 CPUs)
16 GB RAM
128 GB SSD
CentOS-6.3 (x86_64 Latest version)
Linux Kernel Version 3.6.8
Apache Server 2.4.3
PHP 5.4.9
MySQL 5.5.28
WHM/cPanel version: 11.34.0 (build 9)
PHP Extension: Mysqli
Apache Module: mod_deflate
InnoDB Tables, Stored Procedures, INNER JOINS are used.
```

Currently my website traffic around 1500+ users online. In future, it will go 3000+ users online.

Total Query Execution: SELECT 90%, INSERT 8%, UPDATE 2%.

Help me to optimize my.cnf file based on the user traffic and hardware configurations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the future ask any dba before not after ... 

It's one 1 TB HD (no ssd i suppose). It  almost impossible to  configure mysql if you have a lot of DML (insert,update,delete) operations. Change HDD to SSD or buy server with more HDD. You can cache reads SELECT but writes ... try paramter innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2. Creat ethis query in server fault.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "required my.cnf file configuration". You'll have to put in reasonable defaults and benchmark against that. All that information you've given is completely useless because it's not clear how that hardware performs.

Also I have no idea why you would have a twelve core system with a 1TB hard drive. For a database server you would get better performance from a 4-core system with either a small RAID-10 array of 10K RPM drives or an enterprise SSD.

If you want performance, you should also use MySQL 5.5 or better. It's significantly faster than MySQL 5.1. You would also need to investigate the [Percona](http://www.percona.com/) MySQL fork to see if that helps at all.